# Warning- A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled

Tags: reactjs

My code :
NameInput.js

```
import React from "react";
const NameInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type={"text"}
        placeholder="N a m e"
        id="name-input"
        className="form-input"
        onChange={(e)=>props.passState.setFormValue(e)}
        value={props.passState.formValue.name}
      />
      <div id="border-name" className="border-div" />
    </>
  );
};
export default NameInput;
```

ConfirmPassword.js

```
import React from "react";
// import { onFormChange } from "../utils/utilFunction";
const ConfirmPassword = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type={"password"}
        placeholder="C o n f i r m P a s s w o r d"
        id="confirm-password-input"
        className="form-input"
        onChange={(e)=>props.passState.setFormValue(e)}
        value={props.passState.formValue.cnfmPswd}
      />
      <div id="border-confirm-password" className="border-div" />
    </>
  );
};
export default ConfirmPassword;
```

**warning in console**

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components
    at input
    at NameInput (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:826:20)
    at div
    at form
    at Form (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:249:5)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at Mainbox (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:122:5)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35:76)
```

**Main code**
**Form.js**

```
import LoginAccount from "./renderIfSignup/LoginAccount";
import CreateAccount from "./renderIfLogin/CreateAccount";
const Form = ({ sendprop }) => {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    pswd: "",
    cnfmPswd: "",
  });
function onFormChange(e) {
    console.log("target : "+e.target.value);
    setFormValue({ ...formValue, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(formValue);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <div id="input-div">
          {sendprop === "signup" ? <NameInput passState={{formValue,setFormValue}}/> : " "}
          <input
            type={"email"}
            placeholder="E m a i l  A d d r e s s"
            id="email-input"
            className="form-input"
            name="email"
            onChange={onFormChange}
            value={formValue.email}
          />
          <div id="border" className="border-div" />
          <input
            type={"password"}
            placeholder="P a s s w o r d"
            id="password-input"
            className="form-input"
            onChange={onFormChange}
            value={formValue.pswd}
          />
          <div id="border" className="border-div" />
          {sendprop === "signup" ? <ConfirmPassword passState={{formValue,setFormValue}}/> : " "}
        </div>
        <div id="submit-btn-div">
          <button type={"submit"} id="submit-btn">
            S U B M I T
          </button>
        </div>
        {sendprop === "signup" ? <LoginAccount /> : " "}
        {sendprop !== "signup" ? <CreateAccount /> : " "}
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
export default Form;
```

I am getting warning in those two component that is NameInput.js and ConfirmPassword.js but not in input bar of Form.js
What is controlled Input and uncontrolled input ? what Am I doing wrong?
Can anyone explain why I am facing this error

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You need to set the initial values of each input to null, instead of undefined. That's probably what the other comment is referring to.

Comment: I am console logging "props.passState.formValue.cnfmPswd" inside NameInput Function  but getting undefined

Comment: how do i set null or empty string?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a lot of mistakes!

1. setState without previous value.
2. Use `e.target.name` but you don't have the `name` attribute in your input tag.
3. Pass wrong handler function to your children components (In your case, I supposed that you want to pass `onFormChange` not the state setter `setFormValue`).

```js
// NameInput.js

const NameInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type={"text"}
        placeholder="N a m e"
        id="name-input"
        className="form-input"
        name="name"  // Missing name attribute here
        onChange={(e) => props.passState.onFormChange(e)}
        value={props.passState.formValue.name}
      />
      <div id="border-name" className="border-div" />
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
// ConfirmPassword.js

const ConfirmPassword = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type={"password"}
        placeholder="C o n f i r m P a s s w o r d"
        id="confirm-password-input"
        className="form-input"
        name="cnfmPswd"  // Missing name attribute here
        onChange={(e) => props.passState.onFormChange(e)}
        value={props.passState.formValue.cnfmPswd}
      />
      <div id="border-confirm-password" className="border-div" />
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
// Form.js

const Form = ({ sendprop }) => {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    pswd: "",
    cnfmPswd: ""
  });
  function onFormChange(e) {
    console.log("target : " + e.target.value);
    setFormValue((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })); // setState with previous value
    console.log(formValue);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <div id="input-div">
          {sendprop === "signup" ? (
            <NameInput passState={{ formValue, onFormChange }} /> // Pass wrong handler function
          ) : (
            " "
          )}
          <input
            type={"email"}
            placeholder="E m a i l  A d d r e s s"
            id="email-input"
            className="form-input"
            name="email"
            onChange={onFormChange}
            value={formValue.email}
          />
          <div id="border" className="border-div" />
          <input
            type={"password"}
            placeholder="P a s s w o r d"
            id="password-input"
            className="form-input"
            onChange={onFormChange}
            value={formValue.pswd}
            name="pswd" // Missing name attribute here
          />
          <div id="border" className="border-div" />
          {sendprop === "signup" ? (
            <ConfirmPassword passState={{ formValue, onFormChange }} /> // Pass wrong handler function
          ) : (
            " "
          )}
        </div>
        <div id="submit-btn-div">
          <button type={"submit"} id="submit-btn">
            S U B M I T
          </button>
        </div>
        {sendprop === "signup" ? <LoginAccount /> : " "}
        {sendprop !== "signup" ? <CreateAccount /> : " "}
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```